# Why does print use for?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> country="Bangladesh"
>>> print(country)
Bangladesh
>>> country
'Bangladesh'
```

When I write `print(country)` then it shows `Bangladesh` and when I write `country` then it shows `'Bangladesh'`; why?

Comment: The second one outputs the `repr(country)`

Answer (score 4):

This only happens if you are in the interactive mode (i.e. you ran `python` or `ipython` from a terminal and start writing commands). If you write code in a script that is supposed to run from that script (i.e. you ran for instance `python script.py` from the terminal), simply writing a variable name does not print anything to the terminal.

In the interactive mode when entering a variable name (let's say `country`) and pressing enter, the interactive shell prints `repr(country)` which is in fact a string, that, if entered into python, would result in the same object as the one saved under the variable name (at least that's what it should be) or a reference to the memory address where the object exists for more complex objects.

For strings this representation is the content of the string surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Although true, this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: True. Added more explanation.